# Formula for the vertex of a linear modulus function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this correct?

Linear modulus function:

$a \vert bx+c \vert + d = y $

Vertex of linear modulus function:

$ (x,y) $

Deriving a formula:

$ y = d $

$a \vert bx+c \vert + d = d$

$a \vert bx+c \vert = 0$

$a(bx+c) = 0$

$bx+c = 0$

$bx = -c$

$x = \frac{-c}{b}$

Vertex of linear modulus function:

$ (x = \frac{-c}{b}, y = d) $

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your result looks good, but I don't see why you're assuming that the vertex is at $(x_0,d)$ for some $x_0$